# UITableViewController always display search bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, search

In iOS 5, is there a way to never hide the search bar in a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean? What have you tried? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend a `UITableViewController` for that then, a `UIViewController` with a `UITableVIew` and `UISearchBar` on top of it and not on the header would do the job. In a more  personal opinion, I wouldn't recommend `UITableViewController` for anything, I find it too much strict for what it really offers. If for some reason I am using a `UITableViewController`and the customer asks me to add a new element to the screen, I am basically screwed.

Comment: I would reccomend the `UITableViewController` if you have text fields. When the keyboard appears the table is shifted its own. On the contary you need to implement your self. Cheers.

Comment: You made a good point there, but still, thank you Apple, but I like to manage my `UIView`s sub-classes the way I want. :)

Comment: Well, I knew I could do what you suggested. I guess I was hoping for something more "flexible". Oh well. I guess I've learned my lesson here.

Comment: You can't have the terms **flexible** and **UITableViewController** in the same sentence, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I found out a solution for this, which works with the classic UITableViewController and UTSearchDisplayController.

I created a container view for the searchBar 1st then put the searchbar inside it. The container must not clip to bounds. After this you can change the position of the searchbar relative to the container. One problem with this that this way the searchbar not handle user interactions. So we need to use our own container which get the events below its real frame.

Our container class:

```
@interface _SearchContainerView : UIView
@end

@implementation _SearchContainerView
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self.subviews.count > 0) {
        UISearchBar *searchBar = (UISearchBar *) self.subviews[0];
        CGRect f = searchBar.frame;
        f = CGRectMake(0, 0, f.size.width, f.origin.y + f.size.height);
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(f, point)) return YES;
    }
    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

If you create the searchBar programmatically you can set the this up with a following like code:

```
- (void)setSearchEnabled:(BOOL)searchEnabled {
    if (searchBar == nil && searchEnabled) {
        searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 44)];
        searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar
                                                                contentsController:self];
        searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
                                     | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
        searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

        searchContainer = [[_SearchContainerView alloc] initWithFrame:searchBar.frame];
        [container addSubview:searchBar];
        container.clipsToBounds = NO;

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = container;

    }  else {
        [searchBar removeFromSuperview];
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
        searchBar = nil;
        searchDisplayController = nil;
        searchContainer = nil;
    }
}
```

Then you can change the position based on the tableView's scroll position:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (searchBar == nil || searchDisplayController.isActive) return;
    CGRect b = self.tableView.bounds;
    // Position the searchbar to the top of the tableview
    searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, b.origin.y, b.size.width, 44);
}
```

And the last part is to restore everything after searching:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    // Restore header alpha
    searchContainer.alpha = 1.0;
    // Place the searchbar back to the tableview
    [searchBar removeFromSuperview];
    [searchContainer addSubview:searchBar];
    // Refresh position and redraw
    CGPoint co = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:co animated:NO];
}
```